# working with c++ library's source code (opencv)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, libraries, multiplatform

I want to ask if it is possible to work with c++ source code of the opencv library, without using the compiled libraries like .lib and .dll.

I mean is it possible to work only with header files and .cpp files from the library?

I want to create a basic c++ class with a function that accepts an image and perform a series of opencv related operations, but I need the freedom to compile the code for a number of platforms as a native library (and I think that using .lib or .dll will forbid the compilation for several platforms). I guess that could be possible by using only the c++ source code. But using visual studio and adding Additional Include Directories, I do get errors LNK2019, that is probably "A function or variable is declared but not defined" although I do include the 'right' directories with .hpp's and .cpp's but probably I miss something.

Comment: You can download the source code and build libraries for your desired platforms yourself, then include them just the same and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical case for native code. What you need to do is download the source code (I believe you have already done that) and build it separately for platform(s) you need it for.

In your project include the result libraries (either static `lib` or dynamic `dll` files) as you would pre-compiled ones. This way library files are kept separate and built only once, not on every build of your project.

In Visual Studio you can set the include path separately for every configuration so you can set your project up to use library built for current architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @slawekwin wrote in his comment above, building and
linking dependencies on your target platforms can also be automated as
part of your build system.

If you built OpenCV before, you should have come across CMake. With
CMake it's possible to configure [external projects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/ExternalProject.html) (EP), which will
download source code of third party project and then configure, build,
and install it. This is an example for OpenCV copied from a [github
repository](https://github.com/arnaudgelas/ExternalProject/blob/master/External-OpenCV.cmake):

```
ExternalProject_Add(opencv
  GIT_REPOSITORY ${git_protocol}://code.opencv.org/opencv.git
  GIT_TAG 2.3.1
  SOURCE_DIR opencv
  BINARY_DIR opencv-build
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND ""
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ${gen}
  CMAKE_ARGS
    ${ep_common_args}
    -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
    -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
    -DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT:BOOL=OFF
    -DBUILD_PACKAGE:BOOL=OFF
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
    -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
#   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
    -DWITH_FFMPEG:BOOL=OFF
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/INSTALL
)

set( OPENCV_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/INSTALL )
set( OPENCV_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/INSTALL )
```

It could also be interesting to take a look at a cross-platform package
manager for C++ called [hunter](https://docs.hunter.sh/en/latest/), which is based on CMake EP.